# Multiple color picker instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make multiple color picker instances on input fields with select buttons to bring the color picker up and reset buttons to clear the fields. The problem is I want to do this without adding loads of separate classes to my markup and then doing loads of separate jquery functions to match it.

Here's the jquery i'm using.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.select_color').click( function(e) {
colorPicker = jQuery(this).next('div');
input = jQuery(this).prev('input');
$(colorPicker).farbtastic(input);
colorPicker.show();
e.preventDefault();
$(document).mousedown( function() {
$(colorPicker).hide();
});
});

$('.select_color').click(function() {
$('.link_color').val($.farbtastic('.color_picker').color);
});

$('.reset_color').click(function() {
  $('.link_color').val('');
  $('.link_color').css('background-color', '#fff');
});
});
```

and here's my markup.

```
function mb_setting_color() {
$options = get_option( 'mb-theme-options' );
?>
<input class="link_color" type="text" name="mb-theme-options[link_color]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $options['link_color'] ); ?>" />
<input type='button' class='select_color button-secondary' value='Select Color'>
<div class='color_picker' style='z-index: 100; background:#f1f1f1; position:absolute; display:none;'></div>
<input type='button' class='reset_color button-secondary' value='Reset'>
<?php
}

function mb_hover_setting_color() {
$options = get_option( 'mb-theme-options' );
?>
<input class="link_color" type="text" name="mb-theme-options[link_hover_color]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $options['link_hover_color'] ); ?>" />
<input type='button' class='select_color button-secondary' value='Select Color'>
<div class='color_picker' style='z-index: 100; background:#f1f1f1; position:absolute; display:none;'></div>
<input type='button' class='reset_color button-secondary' value='Reset'>
<?php
}
```

Is there a way of achieving this without adding more classes and more minimal jquery.